# Combinatorics Puzzle (Circular Table)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q.
Eleven members of a cricket team are numbered 1,2,3..11. In how many ways can they be seated around a circular table so that the numbers of any two adjacent players differ by one or two.

(Procedure Required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with 11. His neighbours must be 10, 9, which separates 10 from 9. So 10's other neighbour must be 8. Hence 9's other neighbour must be 7. Continuing in this way, we see that we must have: 1,3,5,7,9,11,10,8,6,4,2.

Presumably arrangements that differ only by rotation are considered the same. If you also regard arrangements that differ only by reflection as the same, then that is the only arrangement. If you regard 1,2,4,6,8,10,11,9,7,5,3,1 as different, then there are two.

Comment: Its definitely more than 2.

Comment: @user329418 Perhaps you could give me an example other than those two?